# Recommendation for a gui scp client

Tags: applications, ssh, scp

I'm looking for a recommendation for a GUI SCP client that supports private keys.

All of the ones I find don't support private keys.
Thanks

Comment: Could you list the ones you already checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmit by Panic - http://panic.com/transmit/

Configure as an SFTP server, click the Key icon.

I'm not sure of the specific implementation (SFTP vs SCP), but testing onto another standard OS X host with SSH keys setup works fine. The other box isn't running a special SFTP setup - appears to work fine.

Transmit is a great OS X app for any sort of file transfer.